# How to traverse JsonObject?

Tags: json

I need to apply some function to all elements of JSON object. I guess it is named as Visitor or something like that. However JSON object (org.json.JsonObject or net.sf.json.JsonObject) are defined a bit cryptic, so if some one can point on a resource explaining how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are using Java, you can look at the Javadoc to figure out how to use the JSON parser: http://json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html

I am assuming that you need to read each element in the object. Look at the following functions: getNames (this returns all keys) and getString (returns a string of the value corresponding to a particular key).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am so eager, so can't wait until somebody from this wonderful forum helps, so implemented traversal myself. Oh man what I can tell you how the open source products so crappy are, so inconsistent, but still work. Thanks man for your good suggestion. I am happy camper now.

Comment: I can accept no problem, I just feel sorry for people who have a goal in life to get more points in this site reputation. I am really curious what life drive they have, but I guess you can't answer this question

Comment: Nice way to respond to the guy who just helped you out. Keep it up. You're gonna enjoy being here.